# Google maps with android

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, webview

I want to display google maps in my android application. I tried with the google api, but it seems to have problems with API 12 and lower. So i used the example in this page (http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/), but it doesn't seem so work in my API 7 device (xperia 10 mini pro). I used the same code in that page and i get this error after the application starts:

```
10-18 18:04:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(3980): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-18 18:04:55.491: E/AndroidRuntime(3980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.maps.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458fc8e0
```

I get this error even if i did the "Add support library" in the "Android tools" menu, but it doesn't work. I saw that using GM with a web view is not a great idea, so i wanted to fix this problem.

Comment: Post relavant code of GoogleMap instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use 2.2 (API 8) and up inorder to use google maps v2

Answer (score 0):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and make sure that your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.